# Having a adal module issue when integrating with angular 2 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, adal

Has anyone got adal working with angular2 webpack ? struggling at the moment trying to get this module to work
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-adal

getting the error message Cannot resolve module 'adal'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load adal.js in webpack inside Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044892/how-to-load-adal-js-in-webpack-inside-angular-2)

Comment: Please find the working sample of adal @ https://github.com/karthikeyanVK/ng2AzureAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably do the trick:

```
npm install adal-ts --save
```